# Advanced Search for Tables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for a way to filter a table using Javascript. The snippet below is capable of doing so, but only for the whole table.

The advanced filter would be able to search for `index=1` - the way I came up with (but unable to code it) is by binding the headers, e.g. `<th>Index</th>` as criteria.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $("#search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

    $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
          return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });
      
    $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
      $(this).attr('visible','false');
    });

    $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
      $(this).attr('visible','true');
    });

    // Search Count item hits
    var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
    $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');
    if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
      else {$('.no-result').hide();}
  });

  // Parameter Passing
  var queryString = new Array();
  $(function() {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
        
    if (queryString["id"] != null) {
         $('#search').val(queryString["id"])
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.results tr[visible='false'],
.no-result{
  display:none;
}

.results tr[visible='true']{
  display:table-row;
}

.counter{
  padding:8px; 
  color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="search">
      </div>
      <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover results">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
          </tr>
            <tr class="warning no-result">
              <td colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>112</td>
            <td>Content112</td>
            <td>Content2</td>
            <td>Content329</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>SomeOtherContent112</td>
            <td>SomeOtherContent123</td>
            <td>SomeOtherContent3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>329</td>
            <td>DifferentContent123</td>
            <td>DifferentContent2</td>
            <td>DifferentContent329</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: What is `:containsi`?

Comment: Wish I knew, copy pasted it.

Comment: If you want to use this code, best ask the author if such functionality could be added. Otherwise, you could look for a different library that does what you need it to, or even write your own.

Comment: I found [`:containsi`](http://marianoguerra.org/posts/en/case-insensitive-contains-in-jquery-18-containsi.html) it's a jQuery pseudo-class extension that makes filtering case insensitive.

Comment: IMHO, you'd be best served by using a true library like [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: I don't understand what is exactly you are trying to achieve... what do you mean by searching for `index=1`? If you want to literally allow search by specifying a column name, you need to parse the input first and then rewrite the search function so it accepts column name as an argument so it looks for values only in the specified column.

I would go for putting a filter `input` element over every column, so it's easier for the user to filter independently.

Comment: Currently if you search for 112, it will give you the first and second column, because is contained in both (Index and Column1). Let's say I want to search for the index only, `index=112` would only return the first line.